# Can I have a GORM query return the result directly, or do I always have to go through the reference?

Tags: go-gorm

I have a working query where one of the fields is set through a subquery:

```
    // recreate a new user admin with the correct token
    db.
        Save(&Token{
            Value: adminToken,
            User: User{
                UserName: "admin",
                IsAdmin:  true,
                UserType: dbGetUserTypeByName("secops"),  // ← this line
            },
        })
```

`UserType` is of type

```
// UserType is the type of the user: internal, external, ...
type UserType struct {
    ID     uint
    Name   string
    UserID uint // backref to User has-many
}
```

and the table is initialized via

```
db.Create([]UserType{
    {Name: ""}, // empty: will be the default for just a main courante
    {Name: "secops"},
    {Name: "company"},
    {Name: "external"},
    {Name: "api"},
})
```

Finally, the subquery `dbGetUserTypeByName()`:

```
func dbGetUserTypeByName(name string) (userType UserType) {
    db.
        Where(UserType{Name: name}).
        First(&userType)
    return userType
}
```

All of this works fine, my question is: **can I have the result of the query in `dbGetUserTypeByName()` be used directly when initializing the first entry in my question?**

In other words: is there a way to skip the usage of the helper function `dbGetUserTypeByName`?

It seems to me (I am not experienced with GORM, or SQL for that matter) that what is returned by the `db.*` calls is of type [`DB`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm@v1.22.5#DB), and does not contain the actual result of the query (which is retrieved in the variable passed as reference).

I imagined, in non-working-pseudo-GORM-code, something like:

```
    // recreate a new user admin with the correct token
    db.
        Save(&Token{
            Value: adminToken,
            User: User{
                UserName: "admin",
                IsAdmin:  true,
                UserType: db.Where(UserType{Name: "secops"}).First(),  // ← this does not work of course, but you get the idea
            },
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Some GORMS methods, such as db.Save () and db.Create(), return a result with parameters. In the parameters, you can find a method called **Value** which includes the return result parameters.

Example:

```golang
type Entity struct {
  ID string `json:"id"`
  Title string `json:"title"`
}
```

```golang
func CreateEntity (createEntity Entity) (creaeteEntityDB *Entity, err error) {

    result := r.db.Create(&createEntity)

    er := result.Error

    if er != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &createEntity, nil
}
```

***Second method***

Or you can use **Value** parameters

```golang
func CreateEntity (createEntity Entity) (creaeteEntityDB interface{}, err error) {

    result := r.db.Create(&createEntity)

    er := result.Error

    if er != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return result.Value, nil
}
```

But I personally recommend using the first method because by default Gorm does not type parameter **Value**. The **Value** parameter is typed like `interface{}` which is like any.

[image]